# QByteArray::number(int) is only two bytes long

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing a program that sends files from a QT client over to an Android client.

A specific line of code writes the length-prefixed file name string to the stream maintained between them via the following code:

```
qDebug() << socket.write(QByteArray::number((qint32)fileName.length()));
```

I have casted `fileName.length()` into a `qint32`, yet for some reason the above code writes only 2 bytes to the socket's stream (i.e. the console window shows `2` from `qDebug()`).

Is there any reason why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The casting to `qint32` is irrelevant and serves no purpose.

The `QByteArray::number` creates an *ASCII text* representation of the number. In this case, the `fileName.length()` had to have **two** digits and is between 10 and 99. Thus, the contents of the byte array are two ASCII digits. Note that the zero terminator is not included in the `length()` or `size()` of the array, and is thus not transmitted by the socket.

What you are transmitting is *text*, specifically a string that would be `"21"`, had `fileName.length()` been 21.

The code that does what you intend to do is:

```
QDataStream str(&socket);
str << (qint32)fileName.length();
```

The default byte order will be big-endian (network byte order). You can choose the other byte order:

```
str.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
str << ...;
```

Comment: A note about `QDataStream`: it does not handle partial writes and reads. So, unless you have 100% reliable network connection (a localhost or unix domain socket might be close enough), you should not use it directly on a network socket. Instead, use `QDataStream` on a `QByteArray`, and send/receive that.

Comment: @hyde Presumably it's easy enough to check whether things succeeded after you're done? It doesn't "handle" partial writes/reads, but it doesn't crash either.

Comment: Yeah, what I mean is, it's not possible to return partial data to the stream and try again after more data has arrived. State `QDataStream::ReadCorruptData` is unrecoverable, AFAIK.